# jquery unstoppable redirection of page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I working with checking the sessions with PHP and AJAX. my php function to check if the session is set or not, if the session was set it will echo the user details and pass it to jquery ajax, if the session was not set then it will return 0 to ajax then it will redirect to my homepage but it loads too many times like unstoppable i dont know whats happening I dont even have any loop. here's my code.

TIA.

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//iframe id
//iframe onload function
$("#navContent").load(function(){

//check the current session with ajax
$.ajax({

type: 'post',
url: 'http://localhost/impex/lib/uacctload.php',


success:function(data){

    if (data == "0") {
        alert('You are not authorized to view this page.');
        console.log("|chkses|response| : no current session : Response : " +data);

        //iframe redirection to homepage
        $("#navContent").attr('src', "http://localhost/impex/home.html");
        return false;

    }
    else {
        console.log("Current Session Active : Response : OK" );

    }

},
   error:function(xhr, status, error){

   var err =  xhr.responseText;
   alert("Cannot get current session. Contact IT for Support");

   console.log(err);

 }

});//ajax clossing

});//iframe onload closing


});//document ready closing
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

require('getDB.php');
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_username']) && isset($_SESSION['logged_userid'])){

    $sesUname = $_SESSION['logged_username'];
    $sesUID = $_SESSION['logged_userid'];

    $queSession = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccount 
                WHERE acct_uname = '$sesUname' AND acct_id = '$sesUID'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conDB, $queSession);

    while ($userjson = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $userData[] = $userjson;

    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($userData);

}
else
{
    echo "0";
}


?>
```

Comment: is the iframe part of the page you are loading in it `home.html` does this page contain the iframe?  if so it loads the iframe that that then loads itself.  Which again loads an iframe, which loads itself so on infinity.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I get your point. I'll think another way. thanks